# LESSCSS loop with @import (inline) causes "SyntaxError: Recursive variable definition"

Tags: less

I have an array:

```
@styles: amelia, cerulean, cosmo, cyborg, darkly, flatly, fonts, journal, lumen, readable, simplex, slate, spacelab, superhero, united, yeti;
```

And I have my loop:

```
.loopStyles (@index) when (@index > 0) {
  @name: extract(@styles, @index);
  .nb-@{name} {
    @import (inline) 'bower_components/bootswatch/@{name}/bootstrap.css';
  }

  .loopStyles(@index - 1);
}

.loopStyles(length(@styles));
```

However this throws an error: `SyntaxError: Recursive variable definition for @index`.

If I remove the `@import` or if I change the [import option reference](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference) to something other than `less` or `inline`, it works just fine.

What I'm trying to achieve is a way to prefix these extra styles with a class, so I'd prefer if the stylesheet was imported inline rather than referenced.

Comment: It's a [limitation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-import-statements) of using variable interpolation within `@import` statement. The error message is incorrect of course and it's just a bug. I'm afraid currently there's no way to do that within a loop (You'll have to repeat all the import statements by copy-paste).

Comment: Also note that the `(inline)` option won't prepend prefix to the imported styles thus resulting in incorrect CSS. The `(less)` option should do the trick though.

Answer (score 1):

Less docs state "...only variables which have been declared in the root or current scope will be considered and that only the current file and calling files will be considered when looking for a variable. This means that this usage is typically limited to when you inject a variable into the compile process or define a variable at the beginning of your root file."

I've gotten a lot of irrelevant errors while trying to get this to work.

Comment: It's actually improved in recent Less versions. For instance the code above most likely will work in v2.0 and higher (I haven't tested this though). Though it's important to realize that such stuff always will need some extra care and understanding of what's going on exactly because of [lazy-loading](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading).